# Horizontal arrangement of containers

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I want the cards to be arranged in rows of threes, so that when the fourth card is added it will start below the first card. I have trying many unsuccessful methods, please How do I do this?

This is what I have now 
[image]

this is how I want it to be arranged[image]

this is my code

```
 function gotData(data) {
  var jobs = data.val();
  var keys = Object.keys(jobs);

var container = document.getElementById('jobsContainer');
for (var i = 0; i<keys.length; i++) {
var k = keys[i];
var newCard = `
<div class ="container">
<div class="row" id='Card'>
<article class="col-md-4" >
  <div class="cards"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash icon"></span>
    <hr class="divider"/>
    <h2 class="title" id="jobTitle" class="modal-close" onclick="jobDetail();">`+ jobs[k].JobTitle + `</h2>
    <div class="info">
      <hr class="divider"/>
      <p class="lead"><Strong>`+ jobs[k].JobSummary + `</strong></p><a class="btn btn-lg center-block" onclick="location.href = 'Specialistscard.html';">Specialists</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
</article>
</div>
</div>`;
    container.innerHTML += newCard;



}
```

Comment: I would use flexbox instead of bootstrap to acheive this easily.

Comment: your `.row` and `.container` should be in the string only once. You're adding them each time the `for`'s repeating the instructions. :P

Comment: show your CSS also

Comment: As @artur99 said, your loop should contain only `<article></article>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use flexbox instead of Bootstrap. You can probably do the same with Bootstrap but you will have a hard time if your cards are not equal height.

Check out this [flexbox demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygwpBO). I recommend using this excellent [flexbox guide from CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more information.

Also, you have the entire `<div class="row">` in your loop. You should only have the `<article>`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  width: calc(100%/3 - 20px);
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main container containing items you want to position horizontally (such as first, second and last) should have such properties in css:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the for loop is repeating `container` and `row`, and should only repeat `col-md-4`. So you'd change the code like this..

```
function gotData(data) {
     var jobs = JSON.parse(data.val());
     var keys = Object.keys(jobs);

     var container = document.getElementById('jobsContainer');
     container.innerHTML += `<div class="row" id='Card'>`;
     for (var i = 0; i<keys.length; i++) {
         var k = keys[i];
         var newCard = '<article class="col-md-4"><div class="well">'+k+'</div></article>';
         container.innerHTML += newCard;
    }
    container.innerHTML += `</div>`;
}
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/sVucS0OVVQ

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution: make a `div` from `article` and put 
`<div class ="container"> 
<div class="row" id='Card'>`out of your for loop.
example: 
`<div class="container"
 <div class="row" id="Card"  for (var i = 0; i<keys.length; i++) .....`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class ="container">
  <div class="row" id='Card'>
    <div class="col-md-4" >
      <div class="cards"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash icon"></span>
        <hr class="divider"/>
        <h2 class="title" id="jobTitle" class="modal-close" onclick="jobDetail();">`+ jobs[k].JobTitle + `    </h2>
        <div class="info">
        <hr class="divider"/>
        <p class="lead"><Strong>`+ jobs[k].JobSummary + `</strong></p><a class="btn btn-lg center-block" onclick="location.href = 'Specialistscard.html';">Specialists</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" >
      <div class="cards"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash icon"></span>
        <hr class="divider"/>
        <h2 class="title" id="jobTitle" class="modal-close" onclick="jobDetail();">`+ jobs[k].JobTitle + `    </h2>
        <div class="info">
        <hr class="divider"/>
        <p class="lead"><Strong>`+ jobs[k].JobSummary + `</strong></p><a class="btn btn-lg center-block" onclick="location.href = 'Specialistscard.html';">Specialists</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" >
      <div class="cards"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash icon"></span>
        <hr class="divider"/>
        <h2 class="title" id="jobTitle" class="modal-close" onclick="jobDetail();">`+ jobs[k].JobTitle + `    </h2>
        <div class="info">
        <hr class="divider"/>
        <p class="lead"><Strong>`+ jobs[k].JobSummary + `</strong></p><a class="btn btn-lg center-block" onclick="location.href = 'Specialistscard.html';">Specialists</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here si one more solution:

```
function gotData(data) {
  var jobs = data.val();
  var keys = Object.keys(jobs);

var container = document.getElementById('jobsContainer');
var conthead = '<div class ="container">';
var rowhead = '<div class="row" id="Card">';
var enddiv = '</div>';
container.innerHTML += conthead;
container.innerHTML += rowhead;

for (var i = 0; i<keys.length; i++) {
var k = keys[i];
var newCard = `
<article class="col-md-4" >
  <div class="cards"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash icon"></span>
    <hr class="divider"/>
    <h2 class="title" id="jobTitle" class="modal-close" onclick="jobDetail();">`+ jobs[k].JobTitle + `</h2>
    <div class="info">
      <hr class="divider"/>
      <p class="lead"><Strong>`+ jobs[k].JobSummary + `</strong></p><a class="btn btn-lg center-block" onclick="location.href = 'Specialistscard.html';">Specialists</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
</article>`;
container.innerHTML += newCard;
if (((i+1)%3 === 0) && ((i+1) != length)) {
  container.innerHTML += enddiv;
  container.innerHTML += rowhead;
}
}
container.innerHTML += enddiv;
container.innerHTML += enddiv;
```

Comment: I'm getting the error length is not defined .....here (if (((i+1)%3 === 0) && ((i+1) != lenght)))

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. I fixed it now.